# JavaScript set radio button background color

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML

Now, I want to set the background color of the selected radio li element.

I am trying this using this JavaScript

```js
    function radioClicked ( current) {
        if(current.checked) {
           current.parentElement.style.backgroundColor ="#9bb70c";
        } else {
            current.parentElement.style.backgroundColor ="";
        }
    }
```

```html
 <div class="reg-content-wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="">20s</label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" onclick="radioClicked(this)" value="20">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="">30s</label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" onclick="radioClicked(this)" value="30">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="">40s</label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" onclick="radioClicked(this)" value="40">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="">50s</label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" onclick="radioClicked(this)" value="50">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="">60s</label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" onclick="radioClicked(this)" value="60">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="">70s and above</label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" onclick="radioClicked(this)" value="70+">
            </li>
    
        </ul>
    </div>
```

but not working as expected :(

Comment: Clicking on a radio button will always _make_ it checked, so `if(current.checked)` inside your click handler is pointless - this will never _not_ be the case.

Comment: @CBroe is there any workaround?

Comment: @DBS Using JS it's working now with the CBroe solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should hopefully do what you want. Here the selected button is being saved so that when a new button is clicked the previous radio button can be referenced and reset.

```js
   let prev; 

   function radioClicked ( current) {
        if (prev != null) {
              prev.parentElement.style.backgroundColor ="";
        }
        prev = current;
        if(current.checked) {
           current.parentElement.style.backgroundColor ="#9bb70c";
        } 
    }
```

```html
 <div class="reg-content-wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="">20s</label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" onclick="radioClicked(this)" value="20">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="">30s</label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" onclick="radioClicked(this)" value="30">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="">40s</label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" onclick="radioClicked(this)" value="40">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="">50s</label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" onclick="radioClicked(this)" value="50">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="">60s</label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" onclick="radioClicked(this)" value="60">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="">70s and above</label>
                <input type="radio" name="age" onclick="radioClicked(this)" value="70+">
            </li>
    
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with CSS.
with little formatting and use CSS selector `:checked + label`

```css
input:checked + label {
    background-color: #9bb70c;
}
```

```html
<div class="reg-content-wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="20">
                <label for="">20s</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="30">
                <label for="">30s</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="40">
                <label for="">40s</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="50">
                <label for="">50s</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="60">
                <label for="">60s</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="age" value="70+">
                <label for="">70s and above</label>
            </li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
```